# can't figure out with constructors javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor

My code does not work correctly, I can not understand why. when you transfer the card to the shoop, he does not add money to it

```
   function Card (money=0) {
    this.money = money;
}

Card.prototype.addMoney = function(mon) {
  return this.money=this.money+mon;
}

 function CreditCard (money =0) {
this.money = money; 
}

 CreditCard.prototype = Object.create(Card.prototype);

function Shop (card) {
    this.card = card
    this.money=card.money;
    this.addMoney=this.card.addMoney;
}
Shop.prototype = Object.create(Card.prototype);


let card1 = new CreditCard(50);
card1.addMoney(10);//60
card1.addMoney(10);//70
let card2 = new Card(250);
let shop1 = new Shop(card1);
shop1.addMoney(10);//80 but don't work
console.log(card1.money);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
this.addMoney = this.card.addMoney;
```

This is the line with the issue. The function internally references `this.money`, but since the function is now inside the `Shop` class, `this` changes to refer to the shop. So, you have to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the function to the card. The new line would be:

```js
this.addMoney = this.card.addMoney.bind(this.card);
```

Answer (score 0):

A shop is not a card. You should not use inheritance here. A shop *has* a card, so go for composition:

```
function Shop (card) {
    this.companyCard = card
}
Shop.prototype.addMoney = function(mon) {
    this.companyCard.addMoney(mon);
};
Shop.prototype.getMoney = function() {
    return this.companyCard.money;
};
```